# What would be a higher quality alternative to StretchBlt for drawing an HBITMAP?

Tags: image, gdi, stretch

I don't want to use GDI+'s DrawImage because of speed issues.  What other ways are there to draw an image resized with decent quality - at least linear or cubic interpolation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SetStretchBltMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `HALFTONE` setting, but you'll probably run into the same speed issues that you faced with GDI+ -- smoothing always comes at a cost.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to change anything.  Which HDC do I give it?

Comment: @jnm2: Use `SetStretchBltMode` with the destination HDC that you use for `StretchBlt`.

Comment: Thanks!  It's not perfect, but it's much better.