# What Windows library function will shrink a bitmap averaging all pixels?

Tags: windows-xp

I want to shrink a large bitmap such that all source pixels are averaged into the destination pixels. I'm aware that Graphics DrawImage cannot do this regardless of InterpolationMode. For speed and safe code, I want to use a Windows library function. It there one that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969922.aspx) describes how to perform interpolation using WinAPI. However, since you are compressing, not expanding, you may well get away with using [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in conjunction with [SetBltStretchMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (try HALFTONE or COLORONCOLOR and see what gives you better results).

Comment: Thanks but COLOURONCOLOUR's description makes clear it does not do what's required, and nothing in HALFTONE's description suggests it does. Also (please correct me if I am wrong) but surely StretchBlt is not permitted in safe code.

Comment: "and nothing in HALFTONE's description suggests it does" this is true, yet HALFTONE is commonly used to achieve bilinear interpolation (the dithering is a thing of past with todays 24b/32b modes). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4358798/16673 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572886/